# Ruby regex for partial matching in

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I'm trying to match a list of application names with a long list of applications and versions. However, I can't use .include because it returns too many false positives (e.g. "opera" will match with "operating system")

I'd like to be able to read in "qemu" and match it to the following strings:

- `qemu`
- `qemu-kvm`
- `qemu-kvm-1.8`

I've tried

```rb
application.match?("\sqemu\s|w")
```

Comment: Did you mean to use word boundaries? `\bqemu\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird you know you get ten times the points if you write that comment as an answer

Comment: @Max If that if what the OP is looking for, then this should be marked as a dupe. This has been asked many times.

Comment: @Max this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use word boundaries to match your string. That matches on the point between an alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric character.

You should also use a regexp literal because that will handle the escape characters correctly.

```
query = "qemu"
application.match? /\b#{query}\b/
```